# Send email daily from WordPress site

Tags: email, wp-cron

I customized a calendar plugin which shows today's birthdays and current month's list of wedding anniversaries in the home page of the site. I wrote a code in that plugin's displaying page using `wp_mail` and mail will send. But this happens only when the site is visited. My code:

```
if($dat==date('Y-m-d'))/*$dat is the date of event from DB*/
 {
 if($eid!=''){ /*if recipient email id is not null*/
 if($se!=1)  /*if email is sending first time then($se=db column 'send'value) $se=0 otherwise it is 1*/
 {
 $to=$eid;
 $sub="Birthday Wishes";
  $msg='Happy Birthday '.$ev_title[$j];
 $headers= 'From:Mysite <noreply@mysite.com>' . "\r\n".'Content-type: text/html'; 
  $attachments=array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins/spider-event-calendar/images/happybday.gif');
  $rx=wp_mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers,$attachments);
  $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.  "spidercalendar_event",array('send'=>1),array('id'=>$ev_id[$j]));/**/
   //echo "email send";
   }
  else{
      //echo "email already sent";
    }
  }
 }
```

I heard about `wp_cron` but when I searched in this forum about how to write `cron` in WordPress I saw an answer like

> Unfortunately the WordPress cron jobs are only triggered when your site is visited

If it is true then how can I send emails daily even without visiting the webpage? Is there any other way for this?

Comment: This [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126687/22534) offers an extended explanation - and some links - on how *WP Cron* works. Additionally, the wordpress codex has an [overview of WP-Cron Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions). This excellent [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63278/22534) covers both working with *WP Cron* and *Unix Cron* and should get you started. I'm sure there are more resources on here, you just have to make use of the search to find them.

Comment: thank you ialocin..i will go through all the links u shared..

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately the WordPress cron jobs are only triggered when your site is visited

This is true.

The only way to reliably execute code (even if visitors don't visit your site) is to use the unix cron functions.

You can just setup a unix cron job that will do a wget on your homepage.

**Edit**:

You can read [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) to figure out how to setup unix cron job.

Just setup the usual wp_cron and schedule it to run at what ever time you want to run it.

After that setup a unix cron job to do a wget on your homepage. This will trigger a page view which in turn will trigger the wp_cron job.

Comment: can you please share how to do unix cron for the above function? i'm just started to work on wordpress and crons thats y i am asking these many doubts.. plz help me

Comment: Updated my answer.